# STALKER-ish/Tripods YA post-apocalyptic novel series (NOT The Tripods)

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a young adult series, that centres on a bunch of teenagers surviving in a post-apocalypse world on Earth (cliché, I know).

The first book has the following setting:

- Presence of *S.T.A.L.K.E.R*/*Roadside Picnic*-like 'anomalies' where the laws of physics don't apply. In such locations, you can find 'artifacts' that, when combined, create various magical properties e.g. allow you to levitate above the ground.
- The main character is a boy survivalist, and the story starts off with him being captured by a girl 'bounty hunter' or 'loner' of sorts in a bathtub with an 'artifact'. (It makes more sense in context)
- An alien invasion by a force of tripods, attacking with energy beam-like weapons.
- The climax consists of a battle at a dam, where at least three alien factions (all with tripods), of which two were never seen until now, duke it out with each other and the human defenders. The factions are differentiated by the colour of their tripods. I recall a 'water cannon' or two being utilized at some point.

I have read the first book of the series, but couldn't recall the names of either the book or series. Can someone help me out? Google searches with these keywords just didn't turn up any results.

It's not *The Maze Runner*, *Divergent*, *The Hunger Games*, *Mortal Engines* or *The Tripods*. However, this is of a similar genre and nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The Conquered Earth* by J. Barton Mitchell, launched in 2012 with the novel *Midnight City*.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13494718-midnight-city):

> Earth has been conquered by an alien race known as the Assembly. The human adult population is gone, having succumbed to the Tone---a powerful, telepathic super-signal broadcast across the planet that reduces them to a state of complete subservience. But the Tone has one critical flaw. It only affects the population once they reach their early twenties, which means that there is one group left to resist: Children.
>
> **Holt Hawkins is a bounty hunter, and his current target is Mira Toombs, an infamous treasure seeker with a price on her head**. It’s not long before Holt bags his prey, but their instant connection isn’t something he bargained for. Neither is the Assembly ship that crash-lands near them shortly after. Venturing inside, Holt finds a young girl who remembers nothing except her name: Zoey.
>
> As the three make their way to the cavernous metropolis of Midnight City, they encounter young freedom fighters, mutants, **otherworldly artifacts,** pirates, **feuding alien armies,** and the amazing powers that Zoey is beginning to exhibit. Powers that suggest she, as impossible as it seems, may just be the key to stopping the Assembly once and for all.

You can read the scene where Holt (boy bounty hunter) captures Mira (female tinkerer of "Strange Lands artifacts") on [Google books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mqeQPz65kqAC&pg=PT28&lpg=PT28&source=bl&q=Bathtub&f=false#v=snippet&q=Bathtub&f=false), it's the third result.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book post apocalyptic earth teenagers aliens anomaly zones site:goodreads.com/book` which brought up [this review of the second book](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1164302737?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1):

> The world building for this book series with the aliens, the Strange Lands and it's anomalies/ artifacts are my favorite parts

Comment: Dear Jenayah, thanks! This was the right answer - although how did you manage to find it? =) I had use the exact keywords and found nothing - perhaps this is just a quirk with Google =)

Comment: @WeiJianTeoh There is a degree to which Google tunes your search results based on past preferences.

Comment: @Wei exactly what Fuzzy said above: Google results are tailored based on your previous searches, and in my case I hunt for *many* story-ID questions. In this particular case this was my first keywords set, but some other times it takes more attempts to reach a successful query, and each time Google filters out stuff that it feels you're less likely to be interested in.

Comment: Great to know that, thank you! =)